# Why php function sleep() make streamed media unseekable in chrome

Tags: php, streaming, sleep, audio-streaming

This code returns to user proper audio file that one may rewind to any point.

```
header("Content-Type: audio/webm");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');

$path = "record.webm";
readfile($path);    
die();
```

This code make audio unseekable in chrome just when it finished to downloading.

```
header("Content-Type: audio/webm");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');

$path = "record.webm";
readfile($path);
sleep(1);
die();
```

How to fix this error if I'm going to send recording audio to the user gradually? I'm already thinking about making additional request from js when recording has done to download whole complited audio file in one piece without pendings, but it's realy doesn't look like good optimized solution.

UPD

Ofc it's just a simplified example. Original code looks more like this:

```
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate, private");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header('Transfer-Encoding: chunked');

$filesize = filesize($path);
$chunkSize = 8192;
$cursor = 0;
$file = fopen($path, 'r');

while($filesize > $cursor) {
    $chunk = fread($file, $chunkSize);
    $cursor += $chunkSize;

    echo $chunk;
    flush();

    if ($filesize < $cursor + $chunkSize) { //check if the next chunk is last
        sleep(5); //wait if additional data will be recorded
        clearstatcache(true, $path);
        $filesize = filesize($path);
    }
}

fclose($file);

die();
```

Comment: All sleep() is doing there is pausing the PHP script for a moment, so just delaying it completing the response to the browser, before continuing to send the whole thing. It's not making it download in chunks or anything. Are you actually asking how to create a streaming server? It's not really clear what issue you're having or what practical problem you're trying to solve, if the original code works properly

Comment: You explictly set `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, but you don't send any chunk headers, and it doesn't respond to the `Range` argument. I doubt whether the first piece of code really works.

Comment: Excuse me. Updated it

Comment: Do you mean the code works after you remove `sleep(5)`? But 5 seconds is a long time, have you tried a shorter duration like `usleep(100000)`? Check the browser logs I guess maybe it is waiting for the previous request when you want to seek a new position. BTW the updated code still outputs in a wrong format.

Comment: Even usleep(100000) broke this code unfortunately. usleep(10000) alredy doesn't by the way. But in any case it works grate during the composition downloading, conposition becomes unseekable just when downloading has finished.

Comment: What is the _purpose_ of letting the script sleep here to begin with?

Comment: I'm waiting for additional data. I'm appending additional chunk to my record in real time. So I cannot know finaly record time to send it in http header neither it's pointed in headers of audio file, and I have to waiting it somehow. It's a live audio stream.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when a server sends audio gradually, it's chopped up in to small little pieces of audio. You need buffer mechanisms on the client side and special chopped up audio/video on the server side. This is not easy, but luckily there are standard solutions.

If you want to learn how it works and maybe write your own stream client script, you can read about [Media Source Extensions API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Source_Extensions_API).

If you want a simple solution, you read about [videojs](https://videojs.com/).

I have not clue for the reason for Chromes behavior. Does the same happen when you use Firefox?

Comment: Oh, I have some clues about chrome }:) https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642012 ff really managed with it better, but not about that now. I've tried to use arraybuffer. Actually it was my first solution. But again it has problems with realization diversity in different browsers. They are recording audio in different formats and gonna play it through audiobuffer with different formats, and you should invent some serverside stream transcoding to realize simple browser to browser audiostream. I refused this way because I wanted to keep things simpler.

Comment: @Nik Maybe this will help? There are some formats listed here supported by all browsers. In that case you only have to encode the audio to one format, makes it less complex. You should be able to use ffmpeg for this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs

Comment: I've researched this opportunity too. I'm affraid ffmpeg during live audio stream could make things pretty much more complex :(

Comment: @Nik I hope in a few years this won't be a problem anymore, would be nice if all browsers supported the same formats. For now the best solution may be a simple refresh of either the page of a timer to refresh the audio element.